# Unable to create/connect ad-hoc network in 12.04 with RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have 12.04 installed on my Samsung laptop with RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller. But I can't connect to or create a Ad-hoc network. Whether I need to install any additional drivers for enabling Ad-hoc network?

Comment: An ad-hoc network is a **wireless** network; the RTL8111/8168 is a **wired** Ethernet controller and can neither create nor connect to any wireless networks. Please clarify your question.

Comment: But I can connect to wifi networks available and use the inernet without any difficulty

Comment: Please pastebin the output of `sudo lshw -c network` so we can determine which wireless card you are using.

Comment: *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 130
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 34
       serial: b8:03:05:39:6a:75
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-29-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your card is a wired card. It does not have any sort of transmitter or antenna. You can, however, use a cable, to connect to another computer or a router. An alternative is to buy a wireless adapter. You may install it inside your computer. IT, however, should have an adapter already installed, being a laptop.

Should you try to set up a wired network, you need at least one device to run a DHCP server(many routers do that) or manually assign an IP address to every device.